# Sending data with ajax and jquery - textarea.live('blur')

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create script to edit photos in galery. I have there textbox to insert title of photo and after insert title in it and leave textbox it'll update in database. 
It works ok, when I change title by only one photo, but when I change more titles and then I reload page, all changed photos have the same title (which was insert last). 
Can somebody help me please what is wrong?

There is code which I using now:

```
function UpdateTitle(idPhoto) {
    var id = idPhoto;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('textarea').live('blur',function () {
            var titleVal = $(this).val();        

            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "changeTitle.php",
                 data: {title:titleVal , id:id},
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('.'+id).html(msg);
                 }
           })

       });
    });     
}
```

---

```
<textarea name='title' id='title' onchange='UpdateTitle($idPhoto);' rows='2' cols='22'>$title</textarea>
```

Comment: WHy have you got the function running on onchange and then calling blur?

Comment: This *could* be to ensure the load on blur is only done after a change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a good programming tip rather than answering the question since it has already been answered but this would be cleaner:

```
$('textarea').on('blur',function () {
    var titleVal = $(this).val(), id = $(this).data('id');        

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "changeTitle.php",
         data: {title:titleVal , id:id},
         success: function(msg) {
             $('#'+id).html(msg);
         }
   })
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<textarea name='title' id='title' data-id='$idPhoto' rows='2' cols='22'>$title</textarea>
```

Will work much better and will be less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#'+id)` instead of `$('.'+id)`

And use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `html` to fill a textarea.

So basically you should have

```
$('#'+id).val(msg);
```

(supposing the msg is directly the intended content)

But [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is now deprecated. It's suggested you use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like this :

```
 $(document).on('blur', 'textarea',function () { // something more precise than "document" would be better
```

Comment: Yes, $('.'+id) sticks to an html class, whereas # is for a unique html id.