# Asynchronous call triggered by leaving textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So, I'd like to avoid using jquery directly, I want to use Ajax.BeginForm instead. My problem is that I need the ajax part executing upon leaving a textbox field instead of hitting the submit button. Is that possible, or I have to use jquery functions in this case? (If so, where should I start learning about it?)

Comment: For this particular problem you only need to use [jQuery.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).  It shouldn't take more than 10 mins to learn how to use that.  I can't see you learning the non-jQuery way any faster.

Comment: This is exactly what jQuery is made for tho ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203344/sending-data-with-ajax-and-jquery-textarea-liveblur/11203458#11203458

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using jQuery directly? It gives you more control than using helper methods like `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Answer (score 0):

just put an `id` tag on your textbox and use:

```
$( "#textboxID" ).blur(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203344/sending-data-with-ajax-and-jquery-textarea-liveblur/11203458#answer-11203458